# Prove (or disprove) that $1$ is the only integer of the form $(x^4 + 1)/(xy + 1)$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, integers

Prove (or disprove) that $1$ is the only integer of the form $\dfrac{x^4 + 1}{xy + 1}$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.[image: Problem posted in picture format]

Comment: Welcome to MSE: what you have written is a (repetitive) sequence of commands and not a question.

Answer (score 2):

$x = 8, y = 2$ ${{{{{{{}}}}}}}$

Comment: I appreciate that you found this.  How did you arrive with these values and is there a way to generate other solutions?

Comment: @jeremy.m.williams One way to arrive at this solution is as follows: we know that, for odd $m$ and natural $n$, $a^n+1\mid a^{mn}+1$. We can try to use this. So if we take $x=a^i,y=a^j$, then we want $a^{i+j}+1\mid a^{4i}+1$, which will be implied by $\frac{4i}{i+j}$ being odd. Little trial and error gives $i=3,j=1$ and a working solution.